Tikz Style with two parameters and default values
I try to create a tikz style which takes one or two parameters, where the second parameter should be optional. According to other questions and the tikz / pgf doc, the .default should be used to set the default, but this seems not to be working. What am I doing wrong?
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc, decorations.markings, arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=1cm and 2.5cm,
    block/.style={
        rectangle, draw, rounded corners,
        minimum height=5em, minimum width=3.5em,
        align=center,
        inner sep=1em,
    },
    bus/.default={}{0.5},  % Default -> Not working?
    bus/.style 2 args={
        thick,
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position #2 with {\node[font=\footnotesize] {/};\node[below=1pt] {\small #1};},
            mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[semithick]{open triangle 60}}
        },
        double distance=0.8pt,
        shorten >= 5.5pt,
        preaction={decorate},
        postaction={draw, line width=1.4pt, white,shorten >= 4.5pt}
    },
    ]

    % Forward Path
    \node[block]                (A) {A};
    \node[block, right=of A]    (B) {B};

    \draw[bus={3}{0.5}] (A) -- (B) node[midway, above] {$X$};
    % \draw[bus={3}] (A) -- (B) node[midway, above] {$X$};  % Not working because of missing value for #2
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

When I uncomment the last line (\draw[bus={3}] (A) -- (B) ...) I get the following error:
d:/ApplicationNotes/ControllerStructure/figures/mwe.tex:33: Miss
ing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.33 ...{3}] (A) -- (B) node[midway, above] {$X$};
                                                    % Not working because of...

d:/ApplicationNotes/ControllerStructure/figures/mwe.tex:33: Miss
ing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.33 ...{3}] (A) -- (B) node[midway, above] {$X$};


Hm, in my test of your MWE I didn't get any warnings and errors. ¸It works just fine. What errors you get? What result you expected?

The MWE is working if the last line is commented, if the line is uncommeted I get a Missing number, treated as zero error. I updated the question accordingly.

@If for some image element style you define two options, than at use of this style you must always use both options (explicit or as defined as default). You can not overdrive just one. Your commented line is wrong!

As @Zarko said, the first argument is not optional. If you do bus={3}, #1 is 3 and #2 is empty, leading to the missing number error you see.

So as I understand there is no way to make one argument optional? Or did I just use the wrong kind of argument definition? Would it be possible with style args={argspec}{...}? (Like explained here: https://tikz.dev/pgfkeys#pgf./handlers/.style:args)

no, you can't have an optional argument: either you give no arguments and just use the key, if you've specified a default, or you have to give all arguments. that's true even if you use style n args={spec}{defn} or code n args={spec}{defn}. spec just specifies the form you specify the arguments in. it doesn't let you choose whether they are mandatory or not. it is like \def<name><spec>{<defn>}.

Not exactly the same but the answer applies: Q354967
